# Redis Help- Replacing existing key with specific id with new value

Tags: redis

I am working with the redis-cli tool and querying my redis database.

I am storing my keys in redis in the following fashion

```
H:name:id
```

where `name` is a specific string related to the value data and id is the specific id related to the value data.

In this case, I am trying to input new value data into an existing key, where the id stays the same, but the name is changing in the key (new_name).

`H:name:id -> H:new_name:id` (where -> means to replace)

I am having trouble setting the new value to the existing key, when I change the name to new_name.

Instead redis is creating two different keys,

```
H:name:id
H:new_name:id
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What redis commands are you trying? This should work:

```
rename H:name:id H:new_name:id
```